# string from input: date convert to timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

i have this inputfield:

```
<input type="date" id="filter_date" class="input_filter">
```

and got this string "2014-10-07" from this field but i don't know how to convert this into a timestamp without changing something on the inputfield... i thought about to use a datepicker but this cant be the only solution -.-
i tried some crazy parsing, converting and some functions but all of them didnt work..

so the question is how do i convert this string into a timestamp?

Comment: `new Date('2014-10-07').getTime()` ?

Comment: So in MySQL a TimeStamp looks like `YYYY-MM-DD`. What do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
  var dateString = "2014-10-07";
  var format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
  var result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="input_filter" type="date" id="filter_date" class="input_filter">
```

try this

```
echo $timestamp= strtotime($_POST['input_filter']);
```